# how to make the refinerycms backend go to /admin of /refinery?

Tags: url-routing, refinerycms

Is there any quick and easy way to make the backend go to /admin instead of /refinery?

I looked through the docs as well as looked at the gem itself to find any information on this, however I came up with nothing. If this is not possible without major hacking, that would be great to know as well, to be able to pass that info onto my client (i personally could care less about the route).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following line to `config/routes.rb`. Be aware that this must come **before** `mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'`:

```
match '/administrator' => redirect('/refinery')

# inserted by Refinery:
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
```

This will redirect http://example.com/administrator to http://example.com/refinery which will open up the backend.

Sorry for the delayed response, but I was running into the same problem myself recently.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting you can also configure the route directly in refinery core config, see here: [How do I change the Refinery CMS admin path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691602/how-do-i-change-the-refinery-cms-admin-path)