# How do I change the Refinery CMS admin path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, refinerycms

I have done this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do                                                 

  get 'admin', :to => redirect('/refinery')                                      

  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'                                          

end
```

It allows me to give to my users a friendlier URL, one that makes sense to them, but the path still changes to `localhost:3000/refinery`.

So, how do I do this? Without redirection perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make the refinerycms backend go to /admin of /refinery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195315/how-to-make-the-refinerycms-backend-go-to-admin-of-refinery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT,
sorry you actually can use the file at  config/initializers/refinery/core.rb just add this line

```
config.backend_route= "admin"
```